# Git repository locked on El Capitan

Tags: git, icloud, xcode7, osx-elcapitan

After installing El Capitan on my Mac a few days ago, I can't commit to the repository of my current project. I'm using Xcode 7 (official release) and keep getting this error: `The working copy “My App” failed to commit files. The repository is locked.` I'm not that used to working with git so I would be pleased if someone could tell me how to fix this (either how to unlock it or what else to do if the error message is actually misleading). When trying to commit using `Github Desktop` I keep getting the error `Failed to write index.`

BTW: I moved my project to the cloud (iCloud Drive) -- can this be a problem? Compilation actually works however I experienced some difficulties when trying to compile .tex files directly from the cloud...

Comment: Do you see a file called `/<project-root>/.git/index.lock`?

Comment: Yes I do, need to type fifteen characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the lock file present in your `.git` folder via `rm` or some other system command.  Then, run `git reset` on your repository (be sure you're not within the `.git` folder when you do this).

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll accept the answer tomorrow, I can't do this within 15 minutes after asking the question